# passport.js login authentication is not working for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js

I am new in the developing field. This is my first project and I desperately need help to resolve the issue about CORS.

In my project, I am going to put my website on another domain using an iframe tag. I have used Passport.js local strategy it is not working with CORS for Iframe on another domain.

Please help me how to resolve this issue even let me know should I use JWT or any other strategy.

Following is my passport code

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

// Load User model
const User = require('../models/User');

module.exports = function(passport) {
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'full_mobile' }, (full_mobile, password, done) => {
      // Match user
      User.findOne({
        full_mobile: full_mobile
      }).then(user => {
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'That mobile is not registered' });
        }

        // Match password
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          if (isMatch) {
            return done(null, user);
          } else {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' });
          }
        });
      });
    })
  );

  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });
};
```

I am using cors middleware

```
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: true}));
```

Following is code for login

```
// Login
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/dashboard',
    failureRedirect: '/users/login',
    failureFlash: true
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: What isn’t working? Did you check the dev tools network and console tabs for errors or irregularities? What exactly isn’t working? Are the requests coming through? Did you add logging?

Comment: Only the login fails otherwise the registration, ajax works

Comment: But how does it fail, what errors are there?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is related to the version of the node.js module passport you are using. Our login had an unknown problem with the latest version, 0.5.2, i.e. timed out. Need to check if the parameters updated. Instead the easiest was to return back to 0.4.1.
You can update the version to the one you want with > npm install password@0.4.1 for example.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by using JWT token-based API and sending the cookie with
httpOnly: false,secure:true,sameSite: 'none'

```
res.cookie("token", token, {
  httpOnly: false,secure:true,sameSite: 'none'
});
```